# Force ViewModel Instantiation from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a View `OutputOptionsView` which holds several `UserControls` with options settings which are displayed depending on the selection of a combobox.

I create the `Datacontext` and `Datatemplates` for the `UserControls` within `OutputOptionsView` like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:OutputOptionsViewModel x:Key="vm" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="OptionSettings1" DataType="{x:Type views:OptionSettings1View}">
            <views:OptionSettings1View />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="OptionSettings2" DataType="{x:Type views:OptionSettings2View}">
            <views:OptionSettings2View />
        </DataTemplate>

        ....
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The display of the `OptionSettingsViews` is handled as follows:

```
        <ContentControl Name="OutputOptionsContentControl" Content="{Binding}" >
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OptionSettings1}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AvailableOptionsListSelectedIndex}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OptionSettings2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        ...
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
```

`ItemsSource` and `SelectedIndex` of the ComboBox are bound to the viewmodel class `OutputOptionsViewModel` of the `OutputOptionsView`:

```
<ComboBox Name="AvailableOptionsListComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableOptionsList}" DisplayMemberPath="OptionTitle" 
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding AvailableOptionsListSelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Each of my `OptionSettings` view also gets a ViewModel:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:OptionSettings1ViewModel x:Key="vm" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
...
</Grid>
```

Now my Issue concerns the population of the population of the combobox. I created an Interface containing the OptionTitle which each `OptionsSettingsViewModels` inherits. `AvailableOptionsList` which is the `ItemsSouce` for the combobox is a List of this Interface.

```
public List<IOutputOption> AvailableOptionsList { get; set; }
```

It will be instantiated within the Constructor of the `OutputOptionsViewModel`class.

Within each of the `OptionSettingsViewModel` class constructors I add the respective `OptionsSettingsViewModel` to this List:

```
public OptionSettings1ViewModel()
{
    OutputOptionsViewModel.AvailableOptionsList.Add(this);
}
```

This leads to the following Problem: The combobox isn't populated as long as the OptionSettingsViews aren't instantiated, but they can't be instantiated , because they can't be selected from the empty combobox. 
Therefore I'm looking to force the Instantiation of the OptionSettingsViews.

Comment: A view model that "holds several UserControls" is poor design in the first place. It should instead hold several child view models, and UserControls should be instantiated by DataTemplates for the child view model types.

Comment: @Clemens I meant `View`, already edited in the OP, sorry. So each `ViewModel` only has one View.

Comment: Anyway, if you only set the DataType of a DateTemplate to a certain type, without applying an `x:Key`, the DataTemplate will by used automatically when you assign an instance of the type to the Content property of a ContentControl. "*View model instantiation from XAML*", i.e. from the view is the wrong way round. The view should be created for the view model.

Comment: @Clemens I'm sorry, but I don't follow what you mean I should do by that.

Comment: I tested the following:
Adding an empty hidden Grid at the end of the xaml and setting the datacontext to one o the ´ViewModels` will instantiate it and thus populate my combobox doing exactly what I need. However, as mentioned in the OP I don't think it's good to create hidden items just to force the instantiation. Is there no direct way to do this?

Comment: A ComboBox should be populated from a collection of view model items by assigning or binding its ItemsSource property.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing at the moment. The combobox itemsource is bound to a `List<Interface>()`. I made a Interface for the `ViewModel` classes. Everytime a `ViewModel` is instantiated it is added to the list.

Comment: I don't understand the part *"The combobox is populated from the constructor of each viewmodel"*. Also, you talk a lot about your viewmodels. Please include them into your question, they are obviously part of the confusion.

Comment: @grek40 Yeah, it's rather difficult to explain, sorry for that, but I can't add all the different ViewModels into the Question, that would be too much. However it all boils down to one Question: "Can you force instantiation of a ViewModel class within the XAML manually?"

Comment: No, it all boils down to, whether you are ready to create a [mcve] of your problem. No matter how large the viewmodels, as long as they are the smallest possible example to show your problem, they will fit into the question just fine. Only if they contain unnecessary things from your actual project they will become to large. I gladly read 2 or 5 page long questions if that's what it takes to ask about a perfectly focused problem.

Comment: @grek40 fair enough, I completely started over and wrote the question again. I hope things are explained a bit better now.

Comment: Why are you using List<T> instead of ObserveableCollection<T>? Aren't you binding itemsource?

Comment: I'd completely re-architect this to always instantiate all of the viewmodels, nesting them under the mainviewmodel. You're going to need them, so why not just spin them up in the ctor of the main vm?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling that is actually how I solved it at the moment, however this means that I have to set the datacontext in the code-behind of each optionssettingsviewmodel, which was what I wanted to avoid if possible.

Comment: You really only need one datacontext -- the main vm. You could make that an x:Static in the mainwindow...

Comment: BTW - a resource to be aware of: [the WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments made me think, there is some basic misunderstanding:

> [Lynn Crumbling] I'd completely re-architect this to always instantiate all of the viewmodels, nesting them under the mainviewmodel. You're going to need them, so why not just spin them up in the ctor of the main vm?

and

> [Roland Deschain] that is actually how I solved it at the moment, however this means that I have to set the datacontext in the code-behind of each optionssettingsviewmodel, which was what I wanted to avoid if possible

So, as Lynn said, you should start by registering the sub-viewmodels within the main viewmodel, no need for any view involvement at this point.

Then you can define `DataTemplate` for the **viewmodels**, not for the **views** as you do now.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:OptionSettings1ViewModel}">
    <views:OptionSettings1View />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:OptionSettings2ViewModel}">
    <views:OptionSettings2View />
</DataTemplate>
```

By removing the `x:Key` and changing the `DataType` to the viewmodel type, the templates will be automatically selected to display content of the respective type.

The DataContext of your sub-views will be automatically set from the outside. Do not instantiate a sub-viewmodel within the controls xaml.

In your main `OutputOptionsViewModel`, you should host a collection of the sub-viewmodels. In your combobox, you should directly use this collection as itemssource.

Then just drop all the complicated template selection xaml and directly bind the content to your selected sub-viewmodel:

```
<ContentControl
    Name="OutputOptionsContentControl"
    Content="{Binding ElementName=AvailableOptionsListComboBox,Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: Thx, I will test this out in the next days!

Comment: Just tested this out and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!